# Compass watch: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, ubuntu-22.04

(very not familiar with ruby/gem/sass/compass)

I have installed on my Ubuntu server 22.04, ruby 3.2.1, gem 3.4.10, sass 3.7.4 and compass 1.0.3 for a very small project. I followed a tuto to get everyting installed.

But when I run compass watch, I get this issue:

> NoMethodError on line ["89"] of $HOME/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class
> Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

I checked my dear friend Google, but since I'm not familiar with that, I don't know where to look at... That's why I'm here ^^

Any idea to help me to fix this?

Before being on Ubuntu 22.04, I was on 18.04 and it was working like a charm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [`File.exists?` and `Dir.exists?` were removed from Ruby 3.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/bf97415c02b11a8949f715431aca9eeb6311add2)
- [The compass gem](https://github.com/Compass/compass) hasn't been updated in 9 years and is no longer actively maintained

Whatever tutorial you are following that is telling you to use compass is so incredibly out of date that I do not recommend you continue following it.

If you absolutely must continue using compass then downgrade your version of Ruby from 3.2 to 3.1 or earlier.

Comment: You could also try to alias the removed `exists?` to its corresponding `exist?` method.

Comment: After deeper search after posted this message, this is what I found... There is no requirement to use compass, there should be an alternative to achieve the same goal (sass/scss => css)

Thanks for your help :)